# Request server side JSON data and pass into Galleria 1.5.7 framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, galleria

How to pass JSON object asynchronously retrieved from server using $getJSON callback ( or some other recommended method ) and pass this into the Galleria 1.5.7 dataSource variable as a custom JSON data array ? Online docs shows how to feed a manually created custom data array stored in a JS config file, all working fine - but no docs how to retrieve JSON objects from server.

https://docs.galleria.io/references/data.html

https://docs.galleria.io/options/dataSource.html

Sample lint-validated JSON server data: data.json

{
    "title": "title of art work 1",
    "description": "Description of art work 1",
    "image": "../../../../images/image1_fullscreen.png"
}

Seeing only a blank stage.

> Thanks - working fine now using the lower level jQuery ajax utility function suggested. The server side JSON data also needed a little tweak to encapsulate it with square brackets so that the Galleria framework recognised it correctly for parsing as an array of objects.
>
> > [ 
> >     {
> >         "title": "title of art work 1",
> >         "description": "Description of art work 1",
> >         "image": "../../../../images/image1_fullscreen.png"
> >     }
> >     ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://docs.galleria.io/options/dataSource.html you can use a custom data array, however you need the data before running the Galleria framework.

1. Fetch the data from your server
2. Use that data to run the Galleria framework

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.json',
  success: function(data) {
    Galleria.run('.galleria', {
      dataSource: data
    });
  }
});
```

Or in your case with getJSON:

```js
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    Galleria.run('.galleria', {
      dataSource: data
    });
});
```